# After reading a line from a Tab delimited file and doing a .split , count the number of elements it has split into?

Tags: python, split

I have a text file which is Tab delimited.  I read this line by line into an "array" called lstLine.

Some lines have more elements than others.  And by elements I think you know that means "columns of data".  Some lines have 5 columns of data, others have 7.

How do I count the number of elements that the line I just read has?
Here's my code for getting the line into the lstLine array.

```
for oLine in inputfile:  
...
    lstLine = oLine.replace("\n", "").split("\t")
```

Comment: `len(lstLine)`?

Answer (score 1):

The `split` function returns a `list`. Hence the number of elements in `list` can be extracted from `len()` function.
Use it as follows.

```
lstLine = oLine.replace("\n", "").split("\t")
numElements = len(lstLine)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Fejs mentioned in the comment, just do `len(lstLine)`.

By `split`, you get `lstLine` as a Python `List`, `len(lstLine)` counts number of elements in the list.